# How to select and deselect rows in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I want to get the values from selected rows and store it in an array. And when I deselect a row, I want to remove it from result array. But according to my code how many times I clicked on the row that many times fileName from the row values are added to my result array(selectedRows). My code is :

HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular #grid
      style="width : 603px; height:250px;" class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="searchResults" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="selectionMode"
      [rowMultiSelectWithClick] = true
      (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts:

```
    export class ShowFilesComponent implements OnInit {
            searchResults : Array<String>;
            private seletectedRows :Array<String>;

            columnDefs  = [
                {headerName:"S No", valueGetter: (args) => this.getIndexValue(),checkboxSelection : true,headerCheckboxSelection: true,
                headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,cellRenderer: 'selectedClient'}, 
                {headerName : 'File Name', field:'fileName', sortable:true},
                {headerName : 'word count', field:'wordCount', sortable:true}
              ]
            constructor(private http: HttpClient,private r : Router, private s : FileListService) {
                this.http.get(this.path).subscribe(
                  (data: any) => {
                    this.searchResults = data;
                    console.log(this.searchResults);
                  },
                  error => console.log(error)
                );

               }
            }
            ngOnInit() {}
             onRowClicked(event){
            this.seletectedRows.push(event.node.data.fileName);

                console.log(this.seletectedRows);
}
        }
```

Comment: Current behaviour is expected, because your are simply listening to the `onRowCLicked` event and adding the currently clicked row to array

Answer (score 0):

Use **Array.prototype.push** method like this:

```
onRowClicked(event){
    let temp = 0;
    this.seletectedRows.push(event.node.data.fileName);
    console.log(this.seletectedRows);
}
```

and on deselect use **splice** method. I'm sure that your table/grid component have some deselect event that you can use to implement your removal of element from array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Milos Kovacevic. When I remove a fileName from this.selectedRows I got an error in ag-grid that it cannot find that file as I was delete it in this.selectedRows

Comment: You have to give me more details because i don't know the ag-grid api, i just gave you a common sense approach for solving that problem. Can you give me Stackblitz example or something?

Answer (score 0):

Register a `selectionChanged` handler with the grid, and in your handler use the grid api's  `getSelectedNodes()` method.

```
<ag-grid-angular #grid
      [rowData]="searchResults" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="selectionMode"
      [rowMultiSelectWithClick]=true
      (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)" >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

The event object will have a reference to the grid api which you can use to get the selected rows...

```
onSelectionChanged(event: AgGridEvent) {
  const nodes = event.api.getSelectedNodes();
  // now do something with them....
}
```

Note you don't need to store the nodes in an array yourself - just use the ag-grid's copy which will be kept up to date for you, then you can just use Array.map() to get an array of whatever you want from the node's data.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped please consider up-voting it and marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to listen to the `selection/de-selection` of the row, you need to register to `onRowSelected` event.

below is a sample code from `ag-grid-angular` forum, you can build your logic on top of this (below data is just for demo purpose)

**Angular Code:**

```
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowSelection: 'multiple', // to enable multiple row selection by click
  rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
  rowData: null,
  onRowSelected: onRowSelected // register to rowSelection event
};

function onRowSelected(event) {
     alert("row " + event.node.data.athlete + " selected = " + event.node.selected); // only for debugging purpose
     if(event.node.selected) {
         this.seletectedRows.push(event.node.data.athlete);
     } else {
       const index = this.seletectedRows.indexOf(event.node.data.athlete);
       if(index != -1) {
          this.seletectedRows.splice(index, 1);
       }
     }
}
```

[Working example on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AO8FXkDlmRojtokESsyE?p=preview)

Comment: I wrote the code in same way with minor modification. It works fine now. Thank you@dreamweiver